# Why is the text in the footer tag appearing before I press a button that reveals it?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is my text in the footer element coming before I press a button? I have linked it so that the button reveals the text inside the footer. But the text was already there before I clicked the button, and another set of text from the footer appears when the button was clicked. How should I change my code?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<h2>Amazing performance</h2>
<footer id="Answer">
  <h1>
    <p style="font-size:16px;font-family:verdana;color:Green">Yes</p>
    <h1>
</footer>

<p>Should You buy it?</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to reveal</button>

<p id="A"></p>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, just tested it and it only reveals when clicked

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. In the `<footer>` you have an `<h1>` and then another `<h1>`, with no `</h1>`

Comment: 1. * I have linked it so that the button reveals the text inside the footer* - no, you didn't. You copy the text from one place to another. 2. *Why is my text in the footer element coming before I press a button?* - why would be invisible by default?

Comment: You don't have any code which "reveals the footer". You have code which **copies** the text in the footer (which is in no way hidden) to a paragraph with the ID `A` (which isn't in a footer) when the button is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

The text is already present since your html code already has the footer element in it.

One way to do this to have the visibility element attached to your footer. Set it to "hidden".

When the button is clicked, you change visibility to "visible"

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.php

Answer (score -1):

because you are displaying the Yes text in the DOM with HTML. You need to make display:none in css to the element with id "Answer", and then change it to display:block with JS when the button is click.

```
    <style>
    #Answer{
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <h2>Amazing performance</h2>
    <footer id="Answer">
      <h1>
        <p style="font-size:16px;font-family:verdana;color:Green">Yes</p>
        <h1>
    </footer>
    
    <p>Should You buy it?</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click to reveal</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("Answer");
      x.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```